# Accessing levels

Tags: c++, access-levels

```
c->repo->findById(rid)   ;
```

What I want to do is to use the `findById()` function in a module by accessing it through `c` but the variable I'm trying to use is protected.Is there any way to specify that `Control` class is allowed to access that `repo` and the function which is found in `MedRepo`?Or is another method I could use to go there?I've tryed declaring a variable of type `MedRepo` but I get an vtable error for destructors and I can't geet rid of it.

```
ConsoleUI::ConsoleUI(Control *cu) {
    c = cu;
}
```

Definition of c and it's type

```
 class Control { ...
    protected:
        MedRepo* repo;
        MedValidator* validator;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either add a public getter for the `repo` pointer, or declare `ConsoleUI` as a friend of Control (and maybe of `MedRepo` as well, depends on the access level of `findById()` )

Comment: yup,I already had that getter but I wasn't looking in the right way.Thank you